# Zend Router Chain and matching controller/action issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-framework-routing

i want router to match this URL

http://hawthornfc.localsupportus.com.au/hints

in my routes.ini file i have

```
subdomain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
subdomain.route = ":clubalias.localsupportus.com.au"
subdomain.reqs.clubalias = "\w+"
subdomain.default.clubalias = "geelongscouts"
subdomain.defaults.controller = "index"
subdomain.defaults.action = "profile"

hints.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static
hints.route = "hints"
hints.default.controller = "help"
hints.default.action = "hints"

subdomain_hints.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain
subdomain_hints.chain = "subdomain, hints"
```

My route is matching perfectly ie. subdomain_hints but it goes to index/profile instead of /help/hints

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may delete these lines :

```
subdomain.defaults.controller = "index"
subdomain.defaults.action = "profile"
```

and if you want to route a profile page do the same think as you do for "hints" page and chain it with "subdomain" route.